Taylor-like expansion of a real function on a Boolean domain
Let $G = \{0, 1\}^m$ and $f\colon G \to \mathbb R$ be a function. By interpreting $G$ as a finite abelian group, one can expand $f$ using the Fourier transform.
Namely, let $S\subseteq [m] := \{1, \dotsc, m\}$ be any subset and
$$
  \chi_S(x) = \prod_{i\in S} (-1)^{x_i} = \prod_{i\in S} (1-2x_i)
$$
be the parity function (corresponding to a character in the Pontryagin dual $\widehat G = \mathrm{Hom}(G, U(1))$).
It holds that
$$
  f(x) = \sum_{S \subseteq [m] } \hat f(S) \chi_S(x),
$$
where
$$
  \hat f(S) := \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{x\in G} f(x)\chi_S(x) = \mathbb E_{X \sim \mathrm{Unif}(G)}[f(X) \chi_S(X)]
$$
can be estimated using Monte Carlo sampling.
Hence, $f$ can be written as a linear combination of the parity functions $\chi_S$ and each coefficient for a "small" subset $S$ can be effectively estimated using the Monte Carlo method. For example, for $|S|\le 2$ one can perform $O(m^2)$ integrals, rather than calculating $O(2^m)$ values corresponding to all the possible combinations.

Question: is it possible to effectively expand $f$ in the monomial basis (which would formally resemble the Taylor series)? Namely, is it possible to write
$$
  f(x) = \sum_{S\subseteq [m]} \tilde f(S)  \phi_S(x), 
 $$
where
$$
  \phi_S(x) = \prod_{i\in S} x_i
$$
and $\tilde f(S)$ can be effectively calculated for "small" $S$?
References are very welcome.

Two approaches which do not work
The obvious solution of changing the basis explicitly from $\{\chi_S\}_{S\subseteq [m]}$ to $\{\phi_S\}_{S\subseteq [m]}$ does not scale, as it requires evaluation of all $2^G$ terms $\chi_S$.
Then, I tried to think about introducing a suitable scalar product on the space of functions $G\to \mathbb R$ (not necessarily compatible with the group structure of $G$) such that $\{\phi_S\}_{S\subseteq [m]}$ would be an orthonormal basis under it.
Consider a scalar product of the form
$$
  \langle \phi_{S_1}, \phi_{S_2}\rangle = \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{x\in G} w(x) \phi_{S_1}(x) \phi_{S_2}(x) = \mathbb E_{X\sim \mathrm{Unif}(G)}[w(X) \phi_{S_1}(X) \phi_{S_2}(X)]
$$
for some function $w\colon G\to \mathbb R$. However, when $S_1\cap S_2 = \varnothing$, we have $\phi_{S_1}(x)\phi_{S_2}(x) = \phi_{S_1\cup S_2}(x) = \phi_{S_1\cup S_2}(x)^2$, so that
$$
 0 = \langle \phi_{S_1}, \phi_{S_2}\rangle = \langle \phi_{S_1\cup S_2}, \phi_{S_1\cup S_2}\rangle = 1,
$$
which rules out scalar products of the form specified above.
I would be grateful for suggestions or possible references studying this problem. The expansion in terms of the parity functions (i.e., Fourier analysis on a finite group $G$) is well-studied in the references below.
References

R. O'Donnell, Analysis of Boolean functions
R. de Wolf, A Brief Introduction to Fourier Analysis on the Boolean Cube

